# Linq query with datatable

Tags: linq, datatable

I have this datatable result in c#

```
Date    Employee Job1   Job2   Job3
1/1/2012    a    1      1      1 
1/1/2012    b    2      2      2
1/1/2012    c    2      1      4
1/1/2012    d    4      2      1
1/2/2012    a    3      2      5
1/2/2012    b    2      2      2
1/2/2012    c    3      3      3
1/2/2012    d    1      1      1
1/3/2012    a    5      5      5
1/3/2012    b    2      2      6
1/3/2012    c    1      1      1
1/3/2012    d    2      3      4
2/1/2012    a    2      2      2
2/1/2012    b    5      5      2
2/1/2012    c    2      2      2
2/2/2012    a    3      3      3
2/2/2012    b    2      3      3
3/1/2012    a    4      4      2
```

Now I want a result like this:

Job1:

```
Employee      January       February            March
A             9             5                   4
B             6             7
C             6             2
D             7
```

Please, can anybody suggest me how to do this with "Linq" in c#?

Comment: What if the data is over a number of years?

Comment: This is going to be for a year. Honestly i do not know linq and since it was urgent i wrote it here, meanwhile i am also reading anout linq on internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work (or give you at least an idea):

```
var monthEmpGroups = tblEmpJobs.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new
    {
        Row = r,
        Employee = r.Field<String>("Employee"),
        Year = r.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year,
        Month = r.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Employee);

DataTable tblMonthResultJob1 = new DataTable();
tblMonthResultJob1.Columns.Add("Employee", typeof(string));
var dtf = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;

foreach (var empGroup in monthEmpGroups)
{
    string employee = empGroup.Key;
    var newRow = tblMonthResultJob1.Rows.Add();
    newRow["Employee"] = employee;
    var empMonthGroup = empGroup.GroupBy(mg => new { mg.Year, mg.Month });

    foreach (var empYearMonthGroup in empMonthGroup)
    {
        int year = empYearMonthGroup.Key.Year;
        int month = empYearMonthGroup.Key.Month;
        string colName = string.Format("{0} {1}", dtf.GetMonthName(month), year);
        if (!tblMonthResultJob1.Columns.Contains(colName))
            tblMonthResultJob1.Columns.Add(colName, typeof(int));
        int empJob1Count = empYearMonthGroup.Sum(x => x.Row.Field<int>("Job1"));
        newRow[colName] = empJob1Count;
    }
}

// do the same for the other job types
```

**Update** If you need to add a "total-row" at the "end" as commented:

```
DataRow totalRow = tblMonthResultJob1.Rows.Add();
totalRow["Employee"] = "ALL";
var monthGroups = tblEmpJobs.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new {
        Row = r,
        Year = r.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year,
        Month = r.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month
    })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Month });
foreach (var monthGroup in monthGroups)
{
    int yearAll = monthGroup.Key.Year;
    int monthAll = monthGroup.Key.Month;
    string colName = string.Format("{0} {1}", dtf.GetMonthName(monthAll), yearAll);
    if (!tblMonthResultJob1.Columns.Contains(colName))
        tblMonthResultJob1.Columns.Add(colName, typeof(int));
    int allJob1Count = monthGroup.Sum(x => x.Row.Field<int>("Job1"));
    totalRow[colName] = allJob1Count;
}
```

**Update2**

> I am getting error system.dbnull on this line int

```
empJob1Count = empYearMonthGroup.Sum(x => x.Row.Field<int>("Job1"));
```

> I think there
>   are some null values and it is not able to cast null values while
>   doing sum. Please help, how should i resolve this

You can use this code to default an `int?` to zero:

```
var empYearMonthCount = empYearMonthGroup.Sum(x => 
{ 
    int? job1 = x.Row.Field<int?>("Job1"); 
    int value = 0; 
    if(job1.HasValue) value = job1.Value; 
    return value; 
});
```

Comment: Thank you Tim for your quick reply. I'll try and will let you knwo if it works. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Tim, I am getting this error "Specified cast is not valid.." on foreach (var empGroup in **monthEmpGroups**). Do you think this might be because this datatable is exported from the excel file and the date is "Date" type column so it is not able to cast it into datetime. Should i create a new datatable with columns and datatypes specified and then put this datatable values into this new one. Please share your thoughts. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @user1254053: `Date` is `DateTime` in C#, are you sure that it's not a `string`? Then you need to parse it with `Year = DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("Date")).Year`. You can use the debugger to see what type it is(`tblEmpJobs.Columns["Date"].DataType`).

Comment: Hey Tim, You are genius! You were right, though in excel sheet it was a date column but when I exported from worksheet in datatable it showed a string datatype. Thank you, thank you very much for your suggestions and quick reply. It worked and I am elated. Bless you.

Comment: I want a "Grand Total" row at the end to show the total for each month. Do we have to make changes in this function or should we write another line to get the total for every month and add that to datatable. Please can you suggest how to go about this?

Comment: Do your really need to add a "total-row" at the "end" of a `DataTable`? Understood a `DataTable` as a table in a database. You wouldn't store an aggregated value in a table either.

Comment: @user1254053: Edited my answer to provide the total row (of course untested).

Comment: Perfect!! I have to put this datatable values in excel sheet with grand total at the end and it is working fine. Thanks a lot, much appreciated.

Comment: Tim, I am getting error system.dbnull on this line  int empJob1Count = empYearMonthGroup.Sum(x => x.Row.Field<int>("Job1")); I think there are some null values and it is not able to cast null values while doing sum. Please help, how should i resolve this.

Comment: You can use this code to default an `int?` to zero: `var empYearMonthCount = empYearMonthGroup.Sum(x => 
            {
                int? job1 = x.Row.Field<int?>("Job1");
                int value = 0;
                if(job1.HasValue)
                    value = job1.Value;
                return value;
            });`

Comment: @user1254053: Edited also my answer.

Comment: Tim -can you look into my another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448936/datatable-get-maxdate-from-string-type-column     thanks.

Comment: Tim -can you help me with this one - i have edited my question with new requirement. Thanks

Comment: @user1254053: If your requirement changes you should ask a different question and not edit your old question. That applies all the more to a question with an accepted answer. All my updates above are not the way Stackoverflow works, so i won't edit my answer anymore. Ask a specific question and wait for specific answers.

Comment: Ok, understood, Thnaks