# Datatable - Get max(date) from string type column

Tags: datatable

I have this datatable result in c#

```
DAY      Employee Job1   Job2   Job3
1/1/2012    a    1      1      1 
1/1/2012    b    2      2      2
1/1/2012    c    2      1      4
1/1/2012    d    4      2      1
1/2/2012    a    3      2      5
1/2/2012    b    2      2      2
1/2/2012    c    3      3      3
1/2/2012    d    1      1      1
1/3/2013    a    5      5      5
1/3/2013    b    2      2      6
1/3/2013    c    1      1      1
3/13/2013   d    2      3      4
2/1/2013    a    2      2      2
2/1/2013    b    5      5      2
2/7/2013    c    2      2      2
2/5/2013    a    3      3      3
3/2/2013    b    2      3      3
2/1/2013    a    4      4      2
```

Now i want to find the max date from the first column(MM/dd/yyyy) which should be 3/13/2013. Also note that this column is of string datatype.

Please, can anybody suggest me how to do this with "Linq" in c# or is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` to parse a string to a datatime. This should work:

```
DateTime maxDate = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Max(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("DAY")));
```

However, why is it a string in the first place?

**Edit**
 You should also take the  culture into account which was used to create this string. You have to use this culture again when you parse  the string.

So this results works for different cultures but the result is different as you can see here:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
DateTime maxDate = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Max(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("DAY")));
Console.WriteLine(maxDate);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"); // germany
maxDate = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Max(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("DAY")));
Console.WriteLine(maxDate);
```

Comment: Wow Tim, you are a maestro!! Thank you, it works! I exported this data from an excel sheet and after export the datatable shows this column as string datatype.

Comment: Hi @tim what if a day fields comes as "4/1/2012" ? max date will be taking this

Comment: @Praveen: what date is that, first of April or fourth of January? Have you tried it? Actually I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting between programs can be annoying even if they are made by the same company. This thread is similar and hopefully will point you in the right direction:

[DateTime format mismatch on importing from Excel Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965017/datetime-format-mismatch-on-importing-from-excel-sheet)

if you've confirmed it's a `String`, then have you tried a simple: 
`DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);`?